# Teams-cli using Github actions fails to find package.json

Tags: github-actions, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

Using the below script to publish a Microsoft teams app:

```
steps:
  # Setup environment.
  - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
    with:
      node-version: '14'
  - run: npm install

  - name: Checkout the code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - uses: OfficeDev/teamsfx-cli-action@v1
    with:
      commands: validate

  # Publish the Teams App.
  - uses: OfficeDev/teamsfx-cli-action@v1
    with:
      commands: publish
```

I get the following find package error for both the validate and publish actions:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/ms-teams-tabs-app/ms-teams-tabs-app/node_modules/teamsfx-cli/node_modules/undefined/package.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:497:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:393:35)
    at getVersionString (/home/runner/work/ms-teams-tabs-app/ms-teams-tabs-app/node_modules/teamsfx-cli/lib/cli.js:61:28)
    at /home/runner/work/ms-teams-tabs-app/ms-teams-tabs-app/node_modules/teamsfx-cli/lib/cli.js:87:18
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/runner/work/ms-teams-tabs-app/ms-teams-tabs-app/node_modules/teamsfx-cli/lib/cli.js:30:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/runner/work/ms-teams-tabs-app/ms-teams-tabs-app/node_modules/teamsfx-cli/lib/cli.js:26:12)
    at /home/runner/work/ms-teams-tabs-app/ms-teams-tabs-app/node_modules/teamsfx-cli/lib/cli.js:68:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/ms-teams-tabs-app/ms-teams-tabs-app/node_modules/teamsfx-cli/lib/cli.js:89:4)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1721) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1721) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Running the commands locally through the console or using the Visual Code Teams toolkit both run successfully without issue, I can't see what I might be missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated script to the following to correctly install the required packages:

```
steps:
  # Setup environment.
  - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
    with:
      node-version: '14'
  - uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2.0.1
    with:
        version: 6.12.1
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.1
    with:
      persist-credentials: false
  - name: Install and Build 
    run: | # Install npm packages
      pnpm install

  - uses: OfficeDev/teamsfx-cli-action@v1
    with:
      commands: validate

  # Publish the Teams App.
  - uses: OfficeDev/teamsfx-cli-action@v1
    with:
      commands: publish
```

Answer (score 0):

@RichardMc Did you solve it by yourself already?

One issue I can see from the first version is, you should run `npm install` after `Checkout`, but not before it.

Actually, you don't have to be so troublesome to use the action alone and write the workflow file all by yourself.
There exists CI/CD support for Teams app development which covers platforms of GitHub, Azure DevOps, Jenkins, and other platforms by scripts.
You just need to copy the pre-defined yml files for GitHub and do customizations to suit your own requirements.

Please refer to https://aka.ms/teamsfx-cicd-insider-guide for more details.